# How to Disconnect a google drive account that is no longer available?

Tags: google-drive

Earlier my google drive was synced to my work address. 
Then after I left (and the email was recycled to someone else), I wanted to switch accounts but couldn't.

How does one go about changing your google drive account on a local machine?

The canonical method is (if you have access to your old account) to goto preferences>detach account

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](http://www.calliaweb.co.uk/google-drive-wont-sync/)

> Today I finally decided to fix this problem and came across this on
>   the Google Forum and the solution is to simply to delete the Google
>   Drive preference files.

**Mac OS X Solution**

1. Exit the Google Drive application.
2. Open a Finder window.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
4. In the panel asking for the directory location enter `~/Library/Application Support/Google` (without the quotes)
5. Delete the Drive Folder (not any of the other folders!)
6. Empty your trash can.
7. Open the Drive app and sign in with your new account.

**Windows Solution**

1. Close Google Drive from the task bar – Bottom right near the clock.
2. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> – This will open the Run Command
3. Type `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google` – Replace ‘USERNAME’ with your computer username.
4. Delete the ‘Drive’ Folder
5. Start the Google Drive application and now sign into Google Drive with your new account
6. If your local copy of your Google Drive folder is not empty (ie it contains the data from your old account), you’ll have to set it to sync to a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 the folder name within google folder is "DriveFS" and if you are using multiple accounts check the log in URL and search for the "login_hint" parameter, that's the folder that needs to be removed, is not longer necessary to remove them all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).